# TypeError: pygame.sprite.Sprite.add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem with my code, after running, it said that " pygame.sprite.Sprite.add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int" in the line charS1=CharS(100,100,50,50)

i was expecting a red rect in my window after, but i had those problem

here my code, and yes, almost copy from Youtube, but it went wrong

```
import pygame, os , sys , math 
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Group 5: Female house from Ẻuope")
icon = pygame.image.load(join("img","good-icon.png"))
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
 

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 600
FPS = 40
PLAYER_VEL = 3

window=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))


def get_background(name):
 background = pygame.image.load(join("img",name))
 
 return background


class CharS(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    COLOR = (255,0,0)
def __init__(self,x,y, width, heigth):
    self.rect=pygame.Rect(x,y,width,heigth)
    self.x_vel=0
    self.y_vel=0
    self.mask= None
    self.direction= "right"
    self.animation_count = 0

def move (self, dx, dy):
    self.rect.x += dx
    self.rect.y += dy

def move_right(self, vel):
    self.x_vel = vel
    if self.direction != "left":
       self.direction = "left"
       self.animation_count= 0

def loop(self, fps):
    self.move( self.x_vel, self.y_vel)   
 
def draw(self, win):
    pygame.draw.rect(win, self.COLOR, self.rect)
def draw(window, background,char):
    window.blit(background, (0,0))
    char.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()


 




def main(window):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    background= get_background("backgrd.png")
    charS1=CharS(100,100,50,50) #the problem went here
    run= True
    while run:  
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                run = False
                break
        draw(window, background, charS1)    
    pygame.quit()
    quit()        
              
        
    

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main(window)
```

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error, because the base class `pygame.sprite.Sprite` is not initialized. You didn't invoke the constructor of the base class of (`super().__init__()` ). Also see [`class super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

```py
class CharS(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    COLOR = (255,0,0)
    def __init__(self,x,y, width, heigth):
        super().__init__()                          # <---
   
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(x,y,width,heigth)
        # [...]
```